# transitionFromView doesn't work properly for ios8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I'm trying to use transitionFromView

```
        [UIView transitionFromView:fromView
                            toView:weakSelf.logoFlipTurnPhoneAnimationImageView
                          duration:0.6
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                        completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {}
```

It works for ios7 but in ios8 after the transition the view frame move(to unseen area in the superview) probably by the constraints.

I printed the constrains array before and after

before:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78f0cc60 V:[UIImageView:0x78f0c070(113)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78f0cc90 H:[UIImageView:0x78f0c070(113)]>"
```

after

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78f0cc60 V:[UIImageView:0x78f0c070(113)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78f0cc90 H:[UIImageView:0x78f0c070(113)]>",
"<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x79216d00 H:[UIImageView:0x78f0c070(113)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>",
"<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7b86aaf0 V:[UIImageView:0x78f0c070(113)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>"
```

Any idea why the two constraints was added, and why it cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

selec the view in storyboard or xib and select the view you want to set constraints to.then do reset to suggested constraints

Comment: I don't set constraints they were added by the system after the call of transitionFromView